# ng-enter-stagger animation is not working

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm actually trying to animate a list of div created by ng-repeat.

I want them to appear one by one. So I saw I could use ng-enter-stagger but it's not working.

Here's my CSS :

```
.newsLeft.ng-enter{
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s ;
    opacity:0;
}

.newsLeft.ng-enter-stagger{
    -webkit-transition-delay:2s;
    transition-delay:2s;

    -webkit-transition-duration:0s;
    transition-duration:0s;
}

.newsLeft.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Here's the HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="news in newsList" class="newsLeft" animate-on-load>
  <div class="newsComponent" animate-on-load>
    <hr/>
    <div class="newsDate">{{news.date}}</div>
    <div class="newsSubT2">{{news.title}}</div>
    <div>{{news.content}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AngularJS version?

Comment: angular 1.4.4. Angular version could be the problem ?

Comment: Not sure. Can you show some HTML?

Comment: Have you injected the 'ngAnimate' module?

Comment: I did but doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you share the HTML containing the ng-repeat?

Comment: Don't have the code here but I'm gonna share it Monday. Thank you for your help

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Not for the moment. Still waiting for an answer

Comment: You wrote that you were going to share the code on monday. If you do that I can try to help :)

Comment: Oh ! Strange thing I did it. Ok I'm gonna post it

Comment: What does `animate-on-load` do?

Comment: Done. Ask me if you want more.

Comment: Loading my animation on view change

Comment: Are you using `ngAnimate`?

Comment: Absolutely. Is it a problem ?

Comment: No, just making sure you haven't forgotten to include it :)

Comment: Can you describe in what way it isn't working? They show up without animation? Nothing showing up at all? Is `newsList` populated when you enter the view, or is it done after the controller has been loaded?

Comment: All my animations are working. For the moment I'm fading all the elements at the same time and it works but it seems like stagger doesn't work

Comment: newsList is populated in the controller so I think it's ok. And like I said, they are animated but all together instead one by one

Comment: Works when I'm trying. Can you try without the `animate-on-load` directive?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Mobile or desktop?

Comment: I'll try. Testing with Chrome. Desktop

Comment: Oh ! Seems like stagger works well when I use `ng-if` and a button to make my elements appear. Is it the fault of `animate-on-load`

Comment: Glad you solved it :)

Comment: But i don't know how to animate it on view change xD Any ideas ? And post the response (problem with my directive?) so I can vote for it ;) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I can give you an example soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `animate-on-load` directive, so remove that.

Structural animations are by default disabled during the first one or two digest cycles after a view has been changed. You can override this by using `ng-animate-children="true"` on a parent element.

For example:

```
<body ng-animate-children="true">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/AqSt7jaLk0Nq0RKqvdhx?p=preview

Note that this may trigger other animations in the view (for example for `ng-show`).

If you only want the animations for the `ng-repeat` you can use `ng-if` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="news in newsList" class="newsLeft" ng-if="ready">
  ...
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$timeout(function () {

  $scope.ready = true;
});
```

Comment: I've never heard about animate-children ! My bad. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's not mentioned very often. I added a small update to my answer. And you are welcome :)